# Windbg multiple memory windows

Tags: windbg, analysis, reversing

I have tried to open multiple memory windows but I can't.

I tried to find resolution for this on windbg help and on old version it is possible, however on new version I can't find how to open multiple memory windows. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know it was so simple. Pressing the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+m ​​will open a new window. Up to 4 are possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I do WinDbg debugging, I don't use memory windows at all. And maybe you shouldn't use them either. Why?

When doing debugging for clients, they pay me for that. What they get is a complete protocol of my work. That means, I basically a `.logopen` is my first command and a `.logclose` is my last. Doing anything outside the command window will not be recorded and someone else cannot reproduce the debug session any more (most of my work involves crash dump analysis, not live debugging). Such a log file is also useful for myself, e.g. I can construct a summary of all the commands I used for debugging this kind of problem and I can offer a follow-up workshop for the employees of the company.

Thus, the memory window is useless and I use the `db`, `dd` and related commands instead.

With that statement made, I don't see any issues in WinDbg 6.12 through 6.3.9600. Note the [breaking change in version numbering](https://web.archive.org/web/20161124004210/http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/).

WinDbg Preview (the one from the app store) does not support multiple memory windows right now. It is - well - still a preview. It seems that memory windows have not been important enough for Microsoft employees either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'd found other way to do it.

Comment: @shortdragon: and that is? Please answer your own question, if there's a better answer than this. Although I don't use that feature, I'd like to know how to achieve multiple memory windows.